# How to obtain .rej file from debuild?

Tags: packaging

I'm using debuild with some quilt patches provided, and one of them is failing to apply. It says it makes a rejects file - however there is no such file actually made. How can I retrieve to look at it and figure out what is wrong?

```
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building mudlet using existing ./mudlet_2.0-rc12.orig.tar.gz
patching file src/src.pro
Hunk #1 FAILED at 8.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 27 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 243 (offset 3 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file src/src.pro.rej
dpkg-source: error: LC_ALL=C patch -t -F 0 -N -p1 -u -V never -g0 -E -b -B .pc/project_file/ < mudlet-2.0-rc12.orig.s5Vaub/debian/patches/project_file gave error exit status 1
```

Comment: Why not just manually run the `patch` command and see: `LC_ALL=C patch -t -F 0 -N -p1 -u -V never -g0 -E -b -B .pc/project_file/ < mudlet-2.0-rc12.orig.s5Vaub/debian/patches/project_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debuild` will clean up after itself. As the patches are being handled by [`quilt` [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/quilt), simply run `quilt push -a` to attempt to apply the patches and see any reject file.